# Custom Navigation Bar Not working

Tags: ios, objective-c

So i have a Tab ViewController ---> Navigation ViewController -----> abc view Controller . 
Now i want to Customize the Navigation Bar on Abc View Controller Unique.

so i am writing this in App Delegate.m
in
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions

```
UIImage *special = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-heading-select-timezone.png"];

[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[abcViewController class], nil] setBackgroundImage:special forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

but its not Working now . but it was working 6 Months Ago in a Different App. let me know if i miss something or any Suggestions . 
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can customize it this way because the navigation bar is contained in the `UINavigationController`, not your `abcViewController`. Try putting this code in `-[abcViewController viewWillAppear:]`:

```
UIImage *special = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-heading-select-timezone.png"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:special forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

And this in `-viewWillDisappear:`:

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:nil forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```